# Почему не выводит экранированный текст в tooltip Yii1?

Tags: php, yii2, yii, экранирование

Необходимо вывести экранированный текст в виде всплывающей подсказки.

```
<span class="property-prompt"
      data-toggle="tooltip" 
      data-html="true" data-placement="right" 
      title="<?=Yii::t('app', "These indicate the known reliability of the odometer readings. There are four types of odometer descriptions:
                          <ul>
                              <li>ACTUAL – The mileage reading is believed to be accurate and true.</li>
                              <li>EXEMPT – No code is required, by federal law.</li>
                              <li>NOT ACTUAL – The reading is not accurate or could not be ascertained. This may be due to a variety of reasons — the odometer might have been repaired, or the vehicle in question might have been stolen, among others.</li>
                              <li>EXCEEDS MECHANICAL LIMITS – The odometer was unable to measure mileage because it manually exceeded its capacity.</li>
                          </ul>
                      "); ?>">
```

Должны получить простой список, но вместо этого видны все тэги!
`Yii::t` должен экранировать и старых проектах это работает в новом - нет.
В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\yii\helpers\Html::decode(ваш текст) попробуйте
```